# ASP.NET MVC An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and I'm trying to save data to the database and [this error always pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6X0d.png):

[image: HERE IS THE SCREENSHOT: CLICK ME!]

My code:

```
// Save use to the database
public int CreateUser(UsersModel entity)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DBCon))
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SaveUser", conn);   // call stored procedure
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", entity.Firstname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Middlename", entity.Middlename);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", entity.Surname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", entity.Email);

        int rs = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return rs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the connection string is correct ?

Comment: `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBCon" connectionString="Data Source=SHYEILLA-PC\KIM;Initial Catalog=mvccrudv1;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings> `

Comment: do you have SQL management studio in you machine? kindly try to connect to that instance, but use Windows Authentication. Let us know if you successfully connected to the instance

Comment: Yes I'm using 2012 version .. i can connect usng windows authentication